# Remote shutdown command not working for Windows Embedded computer

Tags: c#, command-line

Remote shutdown command not working for Windows Embedded computer. It is working fine for normal windows computers. Is there something special that we need to do for windows embedded? 
I am trying to send following command from my C# program. Also tried over commandline.

```
shutdown /s /f /m \\192.168.100.2 /t 5 /d u:0:0 /c "The Computer is shutting down"
```

Code looks like following

```
 Process proc = new Process();
 proc.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
 proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
 proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
 proc.StartInfo.FileName = "shutdown.exe";
 proc.StartInfo.UserName = adminName;
 proc.StartInfo.Password = adminPassword;
 proc.StartInfo.Domain = System.Net.NetworkInformation.IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName;

 proc.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(@" /s /f /m \\{0} /t 5 /d u:0:0 /c ""The computer is shutting down"" ", ipAddress);
 try
 {
     proc.Start();
 }
 catch( Exception ex )
 {
      // log
 }
```

Comment: Does your log say anything?

Comment: Do you capture the output of that command so that you can see if it gives you an error message, and not just "it didn't work"?

Comment: Does it work if you execute the shutdown command from the command prompt and doesn't involve C# code at all? The reason I ask is that if it doesn't work from the command prompt either then this is a question for [su] because wrapping a problem in C# code doesn't make it a programming problem.

Comment: It didn't work also from command line directly. 
I get access denied in the exception. Both computers are connected with the same router. And both have got same user as admin.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: please check my answer. Command line tool didn't solve the problem. However the code provided in the answer solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Command line tools didn't work and I ended up writing following code to shutdown computer remotely. However the code will work also for the local computer.

```
public void ShutdownRemotePC(string ipAddress, string adminName, string adminPassword)
        {
            try
            {
                var query = new SelectQuery("Win32_OperatingSystem");

                // create always a new management scope
                // create a default one and get immediate info if connection is be possible
                ConnectionOptions connectionOptions = new ConnectionOptions
                {
                    Impersonation = ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate,
                    EnablePrivileges = true,
                    //changed to packet privacy as some service requires it
                    Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.PacketPrivacy,
                    Username = ipAddress + @"\" + adminName,
                    Password = adminPassword,
                    Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000)
                };
                string name = @"\\" + ipAddress + @"\root\cimv2";
                ManagementScope managementScope = new ManagementScope(name, connectionOptions);

                // if already connected is checked inside connect
                managementScope.Connect();
                if( !managementScope.IsConnected )
                {
                    //Shutdown Failed. Managment Scope could not be connected.
                    return;
                }

                using( var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(managementScope, query) )
                {
                    // impersonate the searcher if not allready done 
                    searcher.Scope.Options.Impersonation = System.Management.ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
                    searcher.Scope.Options.EnablePrivileges = true;

                    using( ManagementObjectCollection found = searcher.Get() )
                    {
                        foreach( ManagementObject os in found )
                        {
                            // Obtain in-parameters for the method
                            using( ManagementBaseObject inParams = os.GetMethodParameters("Win32Shutdown") )
                            {

                                // Add the input parameters.
                                inParams["Flags"] = 12;

                                // Execute the method and obtain the return values.
                                using( ManagementBaseObject outParams = os.InvokeMethod("Win32Shutdown", inParams, null) )
                                {
                                    if( outParams != null )
                                    {
                                        var result = Convert.ToInt32(outParams["returnValue"]);
                                        if( result == 0 )
                                        {
                                            Logger.LogError("Shutdown successfully.");
                                        }

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            catch( Exception ex )
            {
                // Shutdown PC=failed.
            }
        }
```